# Karate gives ReferenceError: variable is not defined (but defined in Background)

Tags: testing, karate, gherkin

Getting `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "my_examples" is not defined` on the following simple code:

```
 Background:
#   * def my_examples_0 = read('my-examples.json')
    * def my_examples = [{ 'name': 'terr' }]

  Scenario Outline: <name>
    * def token = call fetch_token

    Examples:
      | my_examples |
```

Version: **karate-junit5:1.4.1.RC2**
Same behavior if `my_examples_0` is used instead

Issue does not exist for the version **1.2.0** and below